# etwas(Gen/akk) leid sein/werden

Tags: verb

The two questions are the same:

*When to use "werden" instead of "sein" in the expression "etwas leid sein/werden" which means "I am tired of something " mentally...

*Does these follwing phrases means " I am very tired of your lies"  ?

"Ich bin deine Lügen so leid"

"Ich werde deine Lügen so leid "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same difference as in English basically:

Expressing a progess:

> Ich werde deine Lügen leid - I am getting tired of your lies

Expressing a state:

> Ich bin deine Lügen leid - I am tired of your lies